# Cannot find Qt5 for configuring with Cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, paraview

I am trying to configure the post-processor Paraview with Cmake which requires the use of Qt. I downloaded Qt5.1.1. and configure it with MinGW. However, when I'm trying to configure Paraview, I get the following error:

```
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:659 (message):
 C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/mingw48_32/bin/qmake.exe reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as
 "C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/mingw48_32/lib" but QtCore could not be found there.
 Qt is NOT installed correctly for the target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  VTK/GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:57 (find_package)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:664 (message):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check D:/ProjectServer_VIE/PARAVIEW/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for more
 details. 
Call Stack (most recent call first): VTK/GUISupport/Qt/CMakeLists.txt:57 (find_package)
```

I manually pointed Cmake to the qmake.exe directory, but I am not sure how to solve this issue. Hope you can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! Stupid me.... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraview does not support Qt5 right now. [Here](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView%3aBuild_And_Install#Download_And_Install_Qt) is document for right version.